# MATLAB example model does not open

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to learn about [fast restart](http://au.mathworks.com/help/sldo/ug/improving-optimization-performance-using-fast-restart-code.html?refresh=true).

I run the first line of their example and it does not work for me:

```
open_system('spe_engine_throttle')
```

> No system or file called 'spe_engine_throttle' found.

What did I do wrong?

```
ver
```

response:
    http://pastebin.com/kQ0sfBG0

Comment: The documentation you link is part of the Design Optimization toolbox, is this toolbox licensed and installed? What version of Matlab do you use?

Comment: Thanks. This is the response of version: http://pastebin.com/kQ0sfBG0

Comment: Seems to be correct. Maybe your path is configured incorrect. You may try `restoredefaultpath`. Be aware that it removes any 3rd party modifications to the search path, including the ones you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is part of [Simulink Design Optimization](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/sl-design-optimization/), which is not part of your license, based on your output of `ver`.